# ¿Como puedo hacer para que en el textarea se muestre el resultado de la operacion?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```js
 <script>
  function suma ()
  {
   var num1=nume1(document.getElementById('num1').value);
   var num2=nume2(document.getElementById('num2').value);
   var resul=nume1+nume2;
   document.getElementById('resul').value;
  }
 </script>
```

```css
 <!-- HOJA DE ESTILO CSS -->
 <style class="color">
  
  * {
   margin-left: 10%;
   margin-right: 10%;
  }

  .cuerpo {
   background: #b3b6b7;
   font-family: poiret one;
  }


  .encabezado {
   background:  #f0f3f4;
   height: 75px;
   z-index: 1;
  }

  .encabezado h1 {
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 25px;
   text-decoration: none;
  }
  .grow:hover {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
   -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
   transform: scale(1.5);
  }

  .calculadora {
   background: #f0f3f4;
   margin-top: 30px;
   padding-top: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   font-family: poret one;
  }

  .calculadora .calcu .datos{
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;

  }

  .calculadora .calcu .select {
   padding-bottom: 20px;
  }


  textarea {
   resize: none;
  }
 </style>
 <!-- HOJA DE ESTILO CSS -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Calculadora</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="cuerpo">



 <div class="encabezado">
  <h1>Juan Daniel Lovato Gamez 25-3614-2014</h1>
 </div>


 <div class="calculadora">

  <form class="calcu" action="">
   <fieldset class="datos">
    <legend>Ingrese los valores</legend>
    <p>Ingrese el primer numero</p>
    <input type="text" name="primerN" maxlength="3" size="20" id="num1">
    <p>Ingrese el segundo numero</p>
    <input type="text" name="segundoN" maxlength="3" size="20" id="num2">
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset class="select">
    <legend>Seleccione la operacion</legend>
    <p>Seleccione la operacion a realizar</p>
    <select name="opciones" id="select">
     <option value="1"> </option>
     <option value="2" id="2" onclick="suma()">suma</option>
     <option value="3" id="3" onclick="resta()">resta</option>
     <option value="4" id="4" onclick="">multiplicar</option>
     <option value="5" id="5" onclick="">dividir</option>
     <option value="6" id="6" onclick="">modulo</option>
     <option value="7" id="7" onclick="">promedio</option>
     <option value="8" id="8" onclick="">maximo</option>
     <option value="9" id="9" onclick="">minimo</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <input class="grow" type="submit" value="Realizar operacion" onclick="">
    <input class="grow" type="reset" value="Borra todo">
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset class="resultados">
    <legend>Resultados</legend>
    <textarea name="resultados" id="resul" cols="60" rows="1"></textarea>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

tengo esta calculadora que tengo que realizar como tarea pero soy nuevo en js y nose como hacer para llamar el resultado al textarea o nose si estoy realizando algo mal en el script, todo esta en un solo documento xq asi me o exige el docente, deante mano gracias para los que deseen ayudarme con esta pregunta

Comment: Creo que en la parte en dónde haces la suma, tienes que cambiar esto: document.getElementById('resul').innerHTML = resul;

Comment: ¿Estas usando solo Javascript o también Jquery?

Comment: como les digo soy nuevo en js y segun yo estoy usando ja

Comment: ¿En que momento quieres hacer la operación? ¿Al seleccionar una opción del `select` o al pulsar el boton `Realizar operacion`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno explico los cambios que hice al ejemplo que compartiste. No se realiza la funciòn de suma porque añades un evento **onclick** a un option, en **Firefox** te funcionaria normal pero en **IE** o **Chrome** no reconoce el evento. Por lo tanto use como disparador el **input Realizar operación** el cual cambie por un button de **type="button"** puesto que si lo dejas tal como esta lo que hará sera mandar la información de tu formulario al [**action**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) que hayas definido (cosa que no hay y solo se queda en blanco). Por otro lado cambie el type de tus inputs de entrada a number para que solo valides si esta vació o es un numero correcto. La demás explicación de la funcionalidad esta en el código de mas abajo. [Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) puedes ver la sintaxis de switch en javascript.

```js
function RealizarOperacion() {
  //Obtenemos los valores de los campos y la operacion selcionada
  var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  var operation = document.getElementById('select').value;

  //aqui validamos que los campo no sean vacios o sean numeros con espacios o puntos demas
  //puedes ser mas preciso diciendo que campo esta mal llenado
  if (num1 == "" || num2 == "" || isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
    alert("Ingrese valores correctos en los campos para realizar la operaciòn.");
    return;
  }
  //como ya sabemos que no sun numeros qu estan bien ahora los parseamos
  num1 = parseFloat(num1);
  num2 = parseFloat(num2);

  //si no son vacios hacemos un switch para que entre en un case por  operacion
  //segun el value del select
  switch (operation) {
    case "1": //no selecciono nada 
      alert("Seleccione una operaciòn");
      break;
    case "2": //selecciono la suma
      Suma(num1, num2);
      break;
  }
}

function Suma(num1, num2) {
  var resul = num1 + num2;
  document.getElementById('resul').value = resul;
}
```

```css
<!-- HOJA DE ESTILO CSS --><style class="color">* {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.cuerpo {
  background: #b3b6b7;
  font-family: poiret one;
}

.encabezado {
  background: #f0f3f4;
  height: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.encabezado h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.grow:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.calculadora {
  background: #f0f3f4;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: poret one;
}

.calculadora .calcu .datos {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.calculadora .calcu .select {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}

</style><!-- HOJA DE ESTILO CSS -->
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Calculadora</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="cuerpo">

  <div class="encabezado">
    <h1>Juan Daniel Lovato Gamez 25-3614-2014</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="calculadora">

    <form class="calcu" action="">
      <fieldset class="datos">
        <legend>Ingrese los valores</legend>
        <p>Ingrese el primer numero</p>
        <input type="number" name="primerN" maxlength="3" size="20" id="num1">
        <p>Ingrese el segundo numero</p>
        <input type="number" name="segundoN" maxlength="3" size="20" id="num2">
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="select">
        <legend>Seleccione la operacion</legend>
        <p>Seleccione la operacion a realizar</p>
        <select name="opciones" id="select">
     <option value="1"></option>
     <option value="2" id="2" onclick="">suma</option>
     <option value="3" id="3" onclick="">resta</option>
     <option value="4" id="4" onclick="">multiplicar</option>
     <option value="5" id="5" onclick="">dividir</option>
     <option value="6" id="6" onclick="">modulo</option>
     <option value="7" id="7" onclick="">promedio</option>
     <option value="8" id="8" onclick="">maximo</option>
     <option value="9" id="9" onclick="">minimo</option>
    </select><br><br>
        <button class="grow" type="button" value="" onclick="RealizarOperacion()">Realizar operacion</button>
        <input class="grow" type="reset" value="Borra todo">
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="resultados">
        <legend>Resultados</legend>
        <textarea name="resultados" id="resul" cols="60" rows="1"></textarea>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo te faltó asignarle el valor a tu textarea.

```
     function suma ()
    {
        //Conviertes a flotante el valor que tienes en el campo de texto 1
        //Si solo vas a trabajar con enteros puedes cambiar parseFloat por **parseInt**
        var num1= parseFloat(document.getElementById('num1').value);
        var num2= parseFloat(document.getElementById('num2').value);
        //Asignas a la variable resul la suma de ambos números
        var resul=num1+num2;
        //Aquí es donde tienes que hacer el cambio
        document.getElementById('resul').value = resul;
    }
```

Comment: gracias amigo, pero sigue sin mostrarme el resultado de la operación

Comment: Donde tienes definido la función nume1 y nume2??

Comment: Edité la respuesta, revisa ahora que tenias unas cuantas cosas mal, te comentarie para que entiendas lo que hice. Te recomiendo que aprendas a usar la consola del navegador, ahi podrás verificar si tienes algún error en tu código javascript. Saludos